# std::array instantiation error

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, containers

Embarrassingly simple problem here. I am trying to use `std::array` and am tripping at the first hurdle with the error ...

```
implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::array<char,10>'
```

The code that gives the error is shown below. I can work around it with `std::map` for now, but I'm sure the fix must be simple!!

```
enum  p_t   {
    EMPTY = 0
    ,BORDER_L
    // ...
    ,BORDER_BR
    ,DATUM
    ,NUMEL    };

class PlotChars
{
    array<char, p_t::NUMEL> charContainer;
    // error on this ^ line:
    //   implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::array<char,10>'
};
```

Comment: If the compiler tells you something isn't defined, make sure you've included its definition.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

My first guess would be that you simply forgot to:

```
#include <array>
```

...before trying to use the `array` template. While you can (at least indirectly) use a few classes without including the headers (e.g., the compiler can create an `std::initializer_list` from something like `{1, 2, 3}` without your including any headers) in most cases (including `std::array`) you need to include the header before using the class template.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a C-style enum, so you probably need to omit the enum name, if your compiler isn't fully C++11 compliant.

```
array<char, NUMEL> charContainer;
```

This works on gcc 4.4.3, whereas the equivalent to your code does not yet work on that version (but does on later ones)

```
#include <array>

enum XX { X,Y,Z };

struct Foo
{
  std::array<char, Y> a;
};

int main()
{
  Foo f;
}
```

Comment: LLVM with C++11 dialect and std lib. Jerry Coffin has the correct solution in his comment

Comment: @learnvst OK, I see. I had just posted a small example that works on an old-ish version of gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Try with that

```
 std::array<char, (int)NUMEL> charContainer;
```

Comment: I see where you are going. This would be the solution if I were using `enum class ...` over plain `enum ...`